# Membership User.IsOnline definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I have a question regarding the membership and more exactly the IsOnline property. I've read some resources but I still don't understand how exactly it is being calculated and how it works, and does it work correctly.

So according to msdn:

> A user is considered online if the current date and time minus the
>   UserIsOnlineTimeWindow property value is earlier than the
>   LastActivityDate for the user.

UserIsOnlineTimeWindow can be configured in the web.config, but what is the default?

Last Activity Date i don't really understand what is last activity date?

And what if user haven't done anything on the website but he is still present there, but he will be shown offline? Is there a way to keep user to be shown online?

What user has to do, that the last activity date was updated?

If anyone can provide me an example with real number i would appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UserIsOnlineTimeWindow can be configured in the web.config, but what is the default?

I don't know what the default value is, but I imagine that if you are planning on using the default behavior of the `IsOnline` property then you would at least want to set the `UserIsOnlineTimeWindow` to a specific value.

> Last Activity Date i don't really understand what is last activity date?

The `LastActivityDate` property is updated to the current `Datetime` whenever you use the `CreateUser` or `ValidateUser` methods. You could also customize other methods of the membership to update the `LastActivityDate`, i.e., `GetUser()`.

> And what if user haven't done anything on the website but he is still present there, but he will be shown offline? Is there a way to keep user to be shown online?

This is where the `UserIsOnlineTimeWindow` comes into play:

```
public bool IsOnline {
    get 
    {
        return ((Datetime.Now - UserIsOnlineTimeWindow) < LastActivityDate)
        //this is the behavior that the MembershipProvider uses by default
        //as you already mentioned in your question
    }
}
```

Based on this information you have a couple of choices:

1. Override the `IsOnline` property with your own implementation
2. Update the `LastActivityDate` property within other Membership methods

> What user has to do, that the last activity date was updated?

By default this will only be updated by the use of `CreateUser`, `UpdateUser` and `ValidateUser`, but as I said before you can customize the `MembershipProvider` to update that property whenever you want.